# C++ Interface declaration/definition and usage

Tags: c++, interface, implementation

I am trying to create a very modular program by using interfaces. Coming from a C# background, I would use interfaces as variable types so I could use polymorphism, allowing myself/others to pass many different objects that inherit from this interface into a function/variable.
However, I am getting many strange errors when trying to do this in C++. What am I doing wrong here?

I would like be able to have interface-typed variables. However, the following produces compilation errors. I think the compiler thinks my ErrorLogger class is abstract, because it inherits from an abstract class or something.

```
ILogger * errorLogger = ErrorLogger();

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'automation::ErrorLogger' to 'automation::ILogger *'
```

If I am going about this the wrong way, even design-wise, I am learning and will gladly listen to any and all advice.

ILogger.h:

```
#ifndef _ILOGGER_H_
#define _ILOGGER_H_

namespace automation
{
    class ILogger
    {
    public:
        virtual void Log(const IError &error) = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

ErrorLogger.h:

```
#ifndef _ERRORLOGGER_H_
#define _ERRORLOGGER_H_
#include "ILogger.h"
#include "IError.h"

/* Writes unhandled errors to a memory-mapped file.
 * 
**/

namespace automation
{
    class ErrorLogger : public ILogger
    {
    public:
        ErrorLogger(const wchar_t * file = nullptr, const FILE * stream = nullptr);
        ~ErrorLogger(void);
        void Log(const IError &error);
    };
}
#endif
```

ErrorLogger.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ErrorLogger.h"
#include "IError.h"

using namespace automation;

ErrorLogger::ErrorLogger(const wchar_t * file, const FILE * stream)
{

}

void ErrorLogger::Log(const IError &error)
{
    wprintf_s(L"ILogger->ErrorLogger.Log()");
}

ErrorLogger::~ErrorLogger(void)
{
}
```

IError.h:

```
#ifndef _IERROR_H_
#define _IERROR_H_

namespace automation
{
    class IError
    {
    public:
        virtual const wchar_t *GetErrorMessage() = 0;
        virtual const int &GetLineNumber() = 0;
    };
}
#endif
```

Compilation Errors:

[image]

Thanks,
-Francisco

Comment: In C++, polymorphism requires using pointers (possibly smart pointers) or references.

Comment: The compilation errors are unreadably small. Can you put them in as plain text instead of a picture?

Comment: Please post actual code instead of images.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Well, even if your classes are concrete and you do `Derived d; Base b = d`, what you get is slicing. So yes, in this case the problem is also with `Base` being abstract, but that's only half of the story ;)

Comment: As @CaptainObvlious notes, actual code in text form is helpful.  The reason is that we can pick it up with our mice, paste it into a test \*.cpp file, and try it ourselves before answering.

Comment: @AndyProwl Ah yeah wasn't even thinking about slicing ;)

Comment: A general observation: you should not have written this much code before testing it.

Comment: @Beta I wrote the code, and then made a design decision to make an error a general interface rather than the COM HRESULTs I was dealing with, for the portability of the code. Adding this IError in broke it. :)

Comment: Your include guard token is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Thank, @chris I changed all my include guards to remove the initial underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ILogger * errorLogger = ErrorLogger();
`errorLogger` is a pointer, you need to initialize it with `new operator`.

The correct way of defining base pointer which points to derieved class is:

```
automation::ILogger * errorLogger = new automation::ErrorLogger();
//                                  ^^^^
```

Better use smart pointers in modern C++:

```
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<automation::ILogger> errorLoggerPtr(new automation::ErrorLogger());
```

Also you need to include `IError.h` in `ILogger.h`

```
#include "IError.h"
```

Other suggestions:

1 use **fstream** isntead of **FILE**
  2 use **std::wstring** instead of **wchar_t ***
  2 in cpp file, dont' call

```
using namespace automation;
```

instead wrap function definitions with namespace, like what you did in header file:

```
namespace automation
{
    ErrorLogger::ErrorLogger(const std::wstring& file, std::ofstream& stream)
    {
    }
}
```

The point is don't mix C++ code with C code, C++ classes like string, fstream provides [**RAII**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), it's safer and easier to use.

Comment: Thank you @billz. While this does work, does this then mean that I cannot initialize an ILogger pointer to an ErrorLogger in the stack? Because the new keyword allocates it in the heap does it not?

Comment: did you "#include "IError.h" in ILogger.h?

Comment: I would argue that using a smart pointer is the correct way. They can be used polymorphically.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations,
the reason I wasn't using smart pointers is for code portability reasons, same reason I am not using #pragma, etc.
As long as there is still a decently easy way to be able to port the code to GC++ I would consider using all of these additions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include "IError.h"` in the `ILogger.h` header file.

Comment: Ah, well that was silly of me. How about my other question?

"be able to have interface-typed variables. However, the following also produces compilation errors. I think the compiler thinks my ErrorLogger class is abstract, because it inherits from an abstract class or something.

ILogger logger = ErrorLogger();

If I am going about this the wrong way, even design-wise, I am learning and will gladly listen to any and all advice."